# IndexOutOfBounds when sending query to webservice

Tags: web-services, soap, wsdl, rmi, indexoutofboundsexception

I get the following strange Exception when I try to send a query to a webservice which should provide a list of specified items.
Any clues? I can also provide more information if necessary.

```
Caused by: javax.xml.ws.soap.SOAPFaultException: java.rmi.RemoteException: Index: 22, Size: 22; nested exception is: 
java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 22, Size: 22
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAP11Fault.getProtocolException(SOAP11Fault.java:178)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.fault.SOAPFaultBuilder.createException(SOAPFaultBuilder.java:119)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:108)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SyncMethodHandler.invoke(SyncMethodHandler.java:78)
at com.sun.xml.internal.ws.client.sei.SEIStub.invoke(SEIStub.java:107)
```

Comment: show some code.. what line causes the exception?

Comment: okay it think I've figured it out: there is a problem with the implementation of the webservice which responds with this exception. So it's actually out of my scope of responsibility. Keep you updated.

Answer (score 0):

For completion: the webservice sent back a message that contained the exception information thus the implementation of the webservice is faulty.
Looking at the raw SOAP messages helps, by adding the argument:

```
-Dcom.sun.xml.ws.transport.http.client.HttpTransportPipe.dump=true
```